# Handling contents of Embed tag in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I access embedded part from web page and contents using selenium and python

```
<embed src="RainPastDailyMonth.php" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Embedded part has input button elements which I need to access using selenium but getting

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 

{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/center/b/input"}
```

for below code

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/center/b/input')
```

where '/html/body/center/b/input' is XPATH for input button

Answer (score 2):

I am able to access the elements in an `<embed>` block by switching frame to `<embed>` element.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > embed'))
```

Here, `'body > embed'` is selector for `<embed>` element.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot.

The `<embed>` element creates an embedded panel in which a third-party 
application can run. In other words: it is outside of the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Selenium is able to operate only on items in the browser's DOM.

You will need to access this third-party application using some other means. [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/) or [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) are popular options.