# watir recursively search for an element inside nested iframe/embed/object

Tags: watir

I have a need to locate elements, whether within the top-level document, or within nested containers (iframe/embed/object).

I've written a recursive version of the elements method, but during testing, I noticed that for container elements that load and render dynamic content, the elements render just fine, but the dynamic content doesn't seem to be available to watir.

## HTML

```
<embed src="https://example.com/">
```

## Ruby

```
element.embeds.each do | embed | 

    puts embed.elements( css: '*' ).length

end
```

This just gives me 0 elements, when I would expect to be able to see the contents of the `embed` too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Watir has no special handling for `embed` elements. However, it seems that Selenium should be able to interact with them if [treated like an `iframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48963817/1200545).

You can add a custom Watir class/method to treat `embed` like `iframe` (specifically the logic for switching to/from inside the `embed` element):

```
module Watir
  class CustomEmbed < IFrame    
  end

  class CustomEmbedCollection < IFrameCollection 
  end   

  module Container
    def custom_embed(opts = {})
      CustomEmbed.new(self, opts.merge(tag_name: 'embed'))
    end

    def custom_embeds(opts = {})
      CustomEmbedCollection.new(self, opts.merge(tag_name: 'embed'))
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use the normal Watir methods:

```
browser.custom_embed(src: 'https://example.com/').elements.count
#=> 13

browser.custom_embed(src: 'https://example.com/').text
#=> "Example Domain\nThis domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.\nMore information..."
```

If this works for you, we can see about adding it to the Watir repository.

Comment: The approach worked perfectly, for both `object` and `embed`. Thanks for the quick turn around!

Comment: Is this something that you'll add to the watir repo?

Comment: Yes, that's the plan. Might take a couple of days. Tied up with other things at the moment.

Comment: Hey Justin, is this still in the queue? TIA